# make menu appear from left for mobile device

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I have a menu using bootstrap.I want the mobile menu comes from left to right, not from top to bottom.Here is my [markup](http://prntscr.com/a1alpm).

[image]

I want to my menu(left one) looks like the right [one](http://prntscr.com/a1aovx).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do check [how to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to post proper question

Answer (score 0):

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/fancy-sidebar-navigation

try this, working good, hope this will solve your issue